# CSS override isn't working (d3 object)

Tags: css, d3.js

I'm trying to apply what I learned in the CSS foundation course (codeschool) to style my d3 objects and so far I'm not getting it right.

I have a bunch of CSS classes which style my charts. I have two types of charts, for the second type I need to override one color.

Main CSS (I didn't create this myself)

```
.horizon {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.horizon {
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}

.horizon + .horizon {
  border-top: none;
}

.horizon canvas {
  display: block;
}

.horizon .title,
.horizon .value {
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.horizon .title {
  left: 0;
}

.horizon .value {
  right: 0;
}
```

Override CSS (For my second type I needed a different color)
(This used to be the first file with changing all horizons to horizon_small which is bad I know.)

```
.horizon .horizon_small {
  border-top: solid 1px #bdbdbd;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #bdbdbd;
}
```

Applying this here:

```
 d3.select("#mychart")
   .selectAll(".horizon")
   .data(data).enter().insert("div", ".bottom")
   .attr("class", ["horizon", "horizon_small"]) // used to be "horizon_small" only
```

but it doesn't work, not sure where the problem is.

Comment: You need to specify the classes as a single string, i.e. `.attr("class", "horizon horizon_small")`.

Comment: okay this .selectAll(".horizon .horizon_small")
          .attr("class", "horizon horizon_small")  only takes horizon into account and not the override

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many things were wrong I went back to my css notes from the tutorial

(1) in the css file, the following means apply horizon_small if the parent is horizon

```
.horizon .horizon_small {
  border-top: solid 1px #bdbdbd;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #bdbdbd;
}
```

while the following means apply both horizon and horizon_small (which is the correct version)

```
.horizon.horizon_small {
  border-top: solid 1px #bdbdbd;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #bdbdbd;
}
```

Next, thanks to the answers/comments, the d3 part should be like the following:

```
 d3.select("#mychart")
   .selectAll(".horizon .horizon_small")
   .data(data).enter().insert("div", ".bottom")
   .attr("class", "horizon horizon_small")
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector ".horizon .horizon_small" targets an element with a class "horizon_small" inside (at some level) some other element with class "horizon". If you want to only target elements with both classes, the selector should be ".horizon.horizon_small".

source : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html

Comment: I did this .selectAll(".horizon.horizon_small")
           .data(data).enter().insert("div", ".bottom")
           .attr("class", ["horizon", "horizon_small"]) but it didn't work. is it how I'm doing it with d3? because it is not applying any of the styles.